# How to sum a single column values based on values in other column?

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I have the following pandas DataFrame df:

```
      fea1  fea2       
0     a_1   1     
1     a_2   2      
2     a_4   3      
3     a_8   7      
4     u     9
5     be_1  5      
6     a_3   24     
7     a_5   5      
8     a_6   8
9     be_4  6
9     a_10  9
10    be_3  1
11    be_2  4
12    be_5  3
13    be_6  2
```

I need to sum up "fea2" values (such as 1,2,24) for a_1, a_2, a_3 and save as a_q1, then sum "fea2" values for a_4, a_5, a_6 and save as a_q2. Also, same for be_1, be_2 and be_3 and so forth. Something like below,

```
      fea1   fea2  
0     a_q1   27      
1     a_q2   16      
2     a_8    7
3     be_q1  10
4     be_q2  11    
5     u      9
```

I tried this

```
df.groupby(df['fea1'].str.extract(r'^(\D+)', expand=False))['fea2'].sum().reset_index()
```

But it sums up all a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4,... as one value and be_1, be_2, be_3, be_4 as... one value.
How to do this efficiently?

Comment: Okay,  How do I determine if I need to group 3 values or 4 values together?

Comment: Are then numbers after the underscore have no gaps.  Meaning that could be in any order by for 1 to 20 all numbers exists and exist only once?

Comment: I wanted it to have like quarters. For ex, Quater 1 : a_1, a_2, a_3. Also, there are no gaps after the underscore. And yes, the numbers exist only once.

Comment: Nope. They are just numbers from 1 to 27.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
df[['Letters', 'number']] = df['fea1'].str.extract('(?P<letters>[a-zA-Z]+)_?(?P<number>\d+)?')
df['grp'] = (df['number'].fillna(0).astype(int) - 1) // 3

df_q = df.groupby(['Letters', 'grp'])['fea2'].sum()
df_q.index = [f'{i}_q{j+1}' if j != -1 else f'{i}' for i, j in df_q.index]
df_q
```

Output:

```
a_q1     27
a_q2     16
a_q3      7
a_q4      9
be_q1    10
be_q2     9
u         9
Name: fea2, dtype: int64
```

Details:

- Use string accessor, `.str` with `extract` and a regex for named capture
  groups.
- Now, let's use a little math to group rows using a divisor of 3
- Next, use `groupby` and `sum`.
- Lastly flatten multiindex header using list comprehension with
  f-string formatting.

Comment: Great! It works. Thank you. One more question. So, what if some values have like a_s1, a_s2, a_s3,... Hope there should only be a small change.

Comment: Yes, you need to modify the regular express.  Regular expression or not extremely easy to learn, but are very userful.

Comment: Do you want the letters to be just 'a' or 'a_s'?

Comment: Here I just stated a few values. But I have a lot more like this and some values are like a_s1, a_s2, a_s3. That's why want it as 'a_s'

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you need to first `sort` on `fea1` and then create a group number on it so you can `groupby`:

```
df = df.sort_values("fea1")

df["group"] = df.groupby(df["fea1"].str[0]).cumcount()//3

print (df.groupby([df["fea1"].str[0], "group"])["fea2"].sum())

fea1  group
a     0        27
      1        16
      2         7
u     0         9
```

Comment: Thank you. But there exists an issue when I have values like a_10, a_20. Because it sorts the fea1 like a_1, a_10, a_11, ..........a_19, a_2, a_20,...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help @Scott Boston. I changed a bit and it worked well. So, here I'm posting the full code along with yours.

```
data = {'fea1':['a_1', 'a_2', 'a_4', 'a_8', 'u', 'a_3', 'a_5', 'a_6', 'a_10', 'a_20','be_1','be_2','be_3','r_s1','r_s2'], 'fea2':[1, 2,3,7,9,24,5,8,3,7,1,8,4,1,2]} 

# Create DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['fea1'] = df['fea1'].str.replace('_', '')
df[['Letters', 'number']] = df['fea1'].str.extract('(?P<letters>[a-zA-Z]+)?(?P<number>\d+)?')
df['grp'] = (df['number'].fillna(0).astype(int) - 1) // 3
df_q = df.groupby(['Letters', 'grp'])['weight'].sum()
df_q.index = [f'{i}_q{j+1}' if j != -1 else f'{i}' for i, j in df_q.index]
df_q  #series

# converting series as dataframe
dff = pd.DataFrame({'fea1':df_q.index, 'fea2':df_q.values})
dff
```